# Getting a TTTAttributedLabel to print bold

Tags: ios, swift, tttattributedlabel

Trying to use the TTTAttributedLabel framework for the first time. I want to use it to make part of my UILabel printed in a bold font and the other part printed light font:

```
let messageLabelString = "\(notificationSenderName) would like to rent your \(notificationItem). Approve?"
cell.messageLabel.text = messageLabelString
let nsString = messageLabelString as NSString
let range = nsString.rangeOfString(notificationSenderName)
let url = NSURL(string: "test")
cell.messageLabel.addLinkToURL(url, withRange: range)
cell.messageLabel.delegate = self
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

I however don't want the blue and underlined font I just want to get a black and bold font. How do I do this?

Comment: Look at `linkAttributes`, `activeLinkAttributes`, `inactiveLinkAttributes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to do what I wanted through:

```
let messageLabelString = "\(notificationSenderName) would like to rent your \(notificationItem). Approve?"
            cell.messageLabel.text = messageLabelString
            let nsString = messageLabelString as NSString
            let range = nsString.rangeOfString(notificationSenderName)
            let url = NSURL(string: "test")

            let subscriptionNoticeLinkAttributes = [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"JohnstonITCPro-Bold", size:15)!
                ]

            cell.messageLabel.linkAttributes = subscriptionNoticeLinkAttributes
            cell.messageLabel.addLinkToURL(url, withRange: range)
            cell.messageLabel.delegate = self
```